# I'm looking for a sample javascript to show different hidden inputs if dropdownlist selected value = a specific value. Anyone have anything?

Tags: drop-down-menu, input, onchange, hidden-field

What code would I start with? I know onChange won't work with input=hidden. Would it be best to write something to re-name the hidden fields and then build it into the existing onchange for the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are wanting to do. I don't believe its possible to make a tag with `<input type="hidden"` show on the browser unless you change its type.

Just tested this at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) and worked on Chrome

```
<input type="hidden" value="OK">

<p id="demo">Click the button below to set the type attribute of the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].setAttribute("type","button"); 
};

</script>

<p>Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not support the setAttribute method.</p>
```

Granted this code obviously states it won't work with IE8 or earlier and it would probably be better to set the id attribute for each of the hidden fields you want and probably use something like `document.getElementById(IDVALUE).setAttribute("type", "text")` Though this will allow the user to change the value in the tag.

Now all that is left is to give a dropdown with an onChange function that runs a statement like above based on what was selected.

Comment: Thanks, I had the on change all set to go, and was able to get it to send the variable hidden field through, the issue was coming with a naming/value title conflict and the getElementById(value) was bypassing certain values and pulling them from other places. (I'm still pretty new at this)